# ASP.NET: ListView display Image based on database column being Null or not

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, listview

I have a database and I'm storing images in it along with a person's name, and other attributes. I've databound my listview with a stored procedure. I want to know how I can display an icon on a row depending on if the record for that row has a picture or not for the person...

I'm not sure how to accomplish this however with the templates in asp.net

If you need me to provide any additional info I can.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is my template and the s where I'm hoping to put them.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td class="width100">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="./Images/PlayerPictures/nothing.gif" title="Picture Available" CssClass="icon right" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="./Images/PlayerPictures/nothing.gif" title="Charts Available" CssClass="icon right" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="./Images/PlayerPictures/nothing.gif" title="Reports Available" CssClass="icon right" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="./Images/PlayerPictures/nothing.gif" title="Video Available" CssClass="icon right" />
        </td>
        <td class="width350">
                <a href="?team=<%# TeamNumber() %>&player=<%# Eval("PlayerKey") %>"><asp:Label ID="PlayerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Player") %>' /></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="PositionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Position") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have no code-behind that is relevant I don't think because the Listview is databound like so...

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView4" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="ListViewPlayersWithFilter"
                                    DataKeyNames="PlayerKey">
```

Comment: Showing your code-behind and markup - or at least the relevant parts - will probably be helpful in getting an answer.

Comment: @Tim, thanks I've added the parts that should be relevant. Anything else just let me know.

Comment: If there is no picture for the person, what do you want displayed?  Just an empty table cell?

Comment: @Tim, I'm using the picture referred to in the code at the moment. It's a 1x1 transparent .gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ListView.ItemDataBound` Event to display an image based on the column value:

Aspx:

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td class="width100">
                    <asp:Literal ID="lblPic" runat="server" />
                    ...
                    ...
                </td>
                <td class="width350">
                        <a href="?team=<%# TeamNumber() %>&player=<%# Eval("PlayerKey") %>"><asp:Label ID="PlayerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Player") %>' /></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="PositionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Position") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        Dim lblPic As Literal = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblPic"), Literal)
        Dim rowView As System.Data.DataRowView
        rowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView)

        If Convert.IsDbNull(rowView("hasPic") = true then
            lblPic.Text = "<img src=\"/Images/PlayerPictures/nothing.gif\" alt=\"Picture Available\" CssClass=\"icon right\" />"
        Else
            lblPic.Text = "<img/> tag to Display Pic"
        End If      
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In the Code.Behind I'm guessing their needs to be a right paranthesis on the second If statement. I'm not getting anything on the page in the `<td class="width100">` it's empty. Shouldn't I be getting at least something there? EDIT: Also where you have the "hasPic" I put my column name where I'm storing my pictures... im guessing that's correct?

Comment: yes u are right, hasPic should be replaced with your column name, second double check if the value of your column is null? (empty != null)...

Comment: this line finds the reference of lblPic defined in your ItemTemplate tags in aspx and assign it to Dim lblPic as Literal object... and with empty != null means empty doesn't mean null so if your column is empty it will go to else statement

Comment: I've set breakpoints at each line inside the `Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound()` and when I debug the site it never hits a breakpoint so im guessing that's the reason it's not showing up. My ListView's ID is "ListView1" so is there something else that should be set to link the Sub with the ListView?

Comment: Got it: I needed to set the OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" inside my <asp:ListView> sorry ;(  Still trying to get used to asp.net and not familiar with how stuff is set up. It works though thanks so much for all your time!